# Smarty Float format thousands without php?

Tags: smarty

So, I'm trying to make smarty format a number like 1000.66 to 1,000.66 but when I use {$number|number_format:0:'.':','} it just rounds it up to 1,001...

I've googled but I can't find anything about it...

Answer (score 0):

|number_format just uses the php function of the [same name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).  Your problem is that you specified the number of decimals as 0, and the function rounds up the number provided. Try with

```
{$number|number_format:2:'.':','}
```